# How to treated pair integer as separated variable?

Tags: c++, queue, std-pair

Is there any way to separate paired integer?
first i declare queue in a way:

```
typedef pair<int,int>pr;
queue<pr>que;
```

i can easily push separate variable in it. e.g.

```
    que.push(make_pair(c,p));
```

now when i take value from queue. i have to take in any paired variable like myp.

```
 pair<int , int> myp = que.front();
```

Now, is there any way to take value in two separate variable from **myp** or directly take value in separate variable from queue?

Comment: Use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), or, if C++17 is available, use [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Comment: Do you know that you can extract values from `myp` simply with `int a = myp.first, b = myp.second;`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that should be an answer I feel

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i didn't know. it's working and also as well **tie**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way to take value in two separate variable from myp

Yes:

```
auto [c, p] = que.front();
```

Those are called Structured Bindings and have been part of the language since C++17.

> is there any way in C++98?

Yes. If you take a look at the documentation of `std::pair`, you'll find that it has two members, `first`, and `second`.

```
int a = myp.first;
int b = myp.second;
```

Comment: is there any way in C++11?